# Nodejs: Find out when a file was last opened? (but not modified!)

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, file, filesystems

Is there a way in nodejs to find out which file of a folder was last **opened / read**? I am not sure if this is possible at all. I am not looking to find the last modified file, but just the last file that was opened by the current user.

(I am on OSX, if this should matter.)

Comment: Assuming the underlying filesystem is POSIX compliant and not mounted in any way that disables access-time updating, you should be able to use the last access time of the file as a sort field. I'm not too familiar with Javascript to know how to do that in offhand, but something like `ls -ut1 | head -n 1` would be a shell command that gets you the file with the latest access time in a directory.  (that's a one as an argument to `ls`, not the letter lower-case L)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe any modern file system tracks last accessed times. It would be bad for performance to require a write whenever some bit of data is read.

**EDIT**: That was incorrect. As Andrew pointed out in his comment, it is actually available in many current file-systems. There's a [table of supported metadata features by file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata) on wikipedia. Notably, it lists FAT12/16/32 and High Sierra (Mac) file systems as not supporting this. NTFS (windows) and HFS (pre high sierra macs) do support it.

Comment: All POSIX-compliant filesystems track last-accessed time.  See [POSIX <sys/stat.h>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html):  `time_t    st_atime   Time of last access.`